# Android 9.0 x86 apps keep crashing - no native bridge

Tags: google-play-store, 9.0-pie, android-x86, arm-processors

So I'm not an expert in Android or in OSes in general although I can make my way around a Linux environment, just to add as a pretext.

I recently installed Android 9 x86 on a Linx 1010b tablet (Intel processor), and I have had many problems launching certain apps that just crash quickly after launching. I have installed and re-installed Android 7 and 8 x86 multiple times and it doesn't matter which version I use, I just have trouble using some apps. I also tend to have a problem installing apps (after about 8 apps installed, play store gets stuck on 'downloading', 'installing', or '95.99 %').

So I did some reading and found it may be to do with something to do with ARM (still not entirely sure what it is), so I decided to enable it, but when I enable the native bridge on my tablet, I get a download manager process, but shortly after stops, and the enabled button switches back to grey 'disabled'. I further found that libhoudini tends to be used for this native bridge, and I searched and couldn't find one for Android 9, and maybe this is why I am unable to enable it. Running `/system/bin/enable_nativebridge` as a super user in the terminal emulator was also ineffective and resulted in the error 'no such file or directory'.

Does anybody have any advice on what I should do? Is this really the source of my problem — not having a native bridge? Is it impossible to run Android with an Intel processor? Is there an alternative to libhoudini? Are there any versions of Android I can use and guaranteed to work — I basically need a few apps and that's it — Microsoft Office, Adobe, Kindle, Udemy, Coursera, and YouTube.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have installed Android x86 on NTFS file system try with other Android x86 old more stable version like Android x86 7.1
With latest stable release or Remix OS or Prime OS